# HttpWebRequest timing out

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have this code that times out as there's a lot of data coming from the server. Does anyone know if there are ways to stop the time outs?

```
    static List<PhraseSource> GetPhrases()
    {
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://aaa.cloudapp.net/api/Phrase/GetJDTO");
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                form = "2", // just get words
                type = "0"
            });
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }
```

Here's my C# server code.  Not sure but maybe there's also a problem there with that but for now it seems to be on the client:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("GetJDTO")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetJDTO([FromBody] GetJDTOOptions options)
    {
        IQueryable<Phrase> query = null;

        query = db.Phrases.AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebRequest` object returned from your call to `HttpWebRequest.Create` has a [`Timeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) property. In the case of [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx), this defaults to 100 seconds.

In your example, you can set this to something higher if you need to. e.g.:

```
...
request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = **numberOfMilliseconds**;
```

You might want to consider paging, etc, as suggested by @thisextendsthat in the question comments, but `Timeout` addresses your specific question.

As you specifically asked about stopping the timeouts altogether, you *can* use [Timeout.Infinite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite(v=vs.110).aspx) (as mentioned in the docs) but that has the potential to destroy your client-side experience, etc.